# Can physics help in choosing watermelons?

Tags: acoustics, everyday-life

Just a lighthearted question for the summer :)

I was at the supermarket the other day, and I wanted to buy a watermelon; great straight out of the fridge, to chill and rehydrate in this sweltering hot weather.
The wisdom my grandma (a farmer in her day) had tried to impart was failing me. I could only vaguely remember something about knocking on the fruit and listening to the sound it would make. Shame I could not tell what sound I should expect (or prefer to any other sound).

So I tried to make up my own criteria.
The main principle I could come up with was that I did not want a dried-out, old fruit, with a lot of air inside, but a plump, juicy one, full of liquid.
So, first thing: the density. Between two fruits of similar volume, I should prefer the heavier one. I found two of the largest, heaviest fruits.
Coming back to the sound, I thought: surely, when there is more air inside the fruit, it will sound 'hollow', which to me meant a 'lower' sound. So I proceeded to knock on the two exemplars, and eventually chose the one producing the higher pitch.

Driving back, I was quite pleased with all this reasoning, when the (infamous) musical glasses experiment suddenly occurred to me. I could not recall whether the pitch was higher or lower when the glass was fuller.
Sure enough, I tried that out when I got home, and it turned out that a fuller glass produced a *lower* sound!

So my whole theory was fundamentally flawed... or was it? Does a watermelon behave like a glass filled with water?

What do you think? Should I have chosen the watermelon with the lower sound? Any other insight?

BTW the one I bought was not too bad and did not look hollow or dry inside, so I can't complain. But maybe the one I did not take was better... just curious to know.

Comment: There is an SE site dealing with food where they do deal with "technical" issues relating to all things food.  It's called [cooking.se].

Comment: I would advise being cautious how much watermelon you consume as a substitute for drinking water, since it is generally high in sugar. Of course in moderation it is fine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has very little to do with physics as we understand it here.

Comment: Personal opinion: There is plenty of room for a physics question about whether one kind of resonator has the same qualitative behaviors as another kind of resonator. Which sound corresponds to better fruit ripeness might be a stretch, but so would a discussion about singing wine glasses that centered on whether they were filled with merlot or with zinfandel.

Comment: I think it is a fun question to think about. I would say watermelon behaves like a filled water, hence, you should choose the one with lower sound. And your reasoning with the density makes sense to me. It is very common to choose a watermelon by tapping it in my country. As far as I know, the experts of this job looks for lower and deeper sounds.

Comment: The physics of watermelons has a history. Years ago at UCSD a professor made a statement about air resistance of ellipsoidal objects. A student disagreed, and to prove his point dropped a watermelon off the top floor of a campus building. A careful measurement of time showed the student was right. The watermelon drop is now reenacted every year. Sad to say, it has degenerated to measuring how far it splatters. It is up to us to restore watermelons to their rightful place in physics!

Comment: https://inhabitat.com/incredible-coating-makes-watermelon-bounce-after-150-foot-drop/

Comment: @all those who provided suggestions and useful comments : thanks!

Comment: In particular @Ekrem : OK, next time I will try the one with lower sound! We will see.

Comment: @StephenG : yes, I know and I posted there for other things; I thought this one would require more physics knowledge than cookery knowledge. I can still post there too and see what users come up with, maybe I shouldn't have discounted that possibility.

Comment: @rob : that's what I thought, too. In the end physics does sometimes have to do with solving practical problems of limited impact, so I did not see the issue.

Comment: @Gert : read the first sentence in my post. I don't know where you live. Where I live it has been months and months of really tough stuff with this Covid and all. I was hoping that just for once, just for this one time, one would be allowed to take a slightly humorous look at life, rather than building more cages, more inflexible rules, more constraints for our souls and our thoughts. Is it not enough to be physically locked up? Must we also lock our minds up?
However, if you really *have* to, and you think this post irreparably harms physics SE, do please yourself and close it down...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a site in greek](https://www.argiro.gr/2019/07/6-mystika-gia-na-dialegete-kalytero-karpouzi/) for choosing watermelons, but the pictures have english:

For slapping it, at the yellowing part (also necessary to have one to be ripe):

> A ready water melon will be full of water and have a deep and hollow sound. In mellon not ripe enough or too ripe, the sound will be dulled.

So the physics enters in interpreting the sound:

My interpretation is that a just right mellon resonates as a whole at low frequencies. A not ripe enough will not resonate well because the flesh will be too firm. On overripe will not connect well to the outside  and will not resonate as well.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!